# What type of power supply do Gridseed G-Blade need?

Tags: mining-setup, gridseed, psu

I have recently purchased 2 Gridseed G-Blade Miners, not realising the power supplies didn't come with them.

Do I need a specific PSU to power them? Or can I get an AC adapter and plug them straight into the wall?

Answer (score 0):

Either solution will work fine. For reference, check out these two setups:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nCjSQMsdlKg

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2QrkWR5HdcQ

The former video illustrates use of AC adapters and the latter illustrates use of an external PSU.